# Why isn't my display name on Meta SO the same as my display name on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, linked-accounts, display-names

My name appears as `user138194` even though on StackOverflow my name is `different`.

My account is associated with the one on Stack Overflow and Server Fault. Also when I visit stack overflow with my vgv8 name I don't see a "meta" link.

How can I use `vgv8` as my meta stack overflow name?

#### Update

I was advised (in comments and answers) to press the "Copy Server Fault Profile to Related Accounts" button. But, this button is not available in SF, probably because vgv8 is suspended on that site.

Can I press the "Copy Stack Overflow Profile to Related Accounts" button?

Comment: Uhm...that's a long shot...but maybe it was because of this behavior?

Comment: Try editing your profile on Meta Stack Overflow, and setting the display name to vgv8. This site doesn't operate with SO the same way that MSF does with SF. The accounts are associated, but not directly linked. As Jon B points out, you're not actually blocked or suspended or *anything* as vgv8 on MSO. You just haven't configured your display name.

Comment: @devinb - I don't think his update is a new question. It is a clarification. He thinks that his vgv8 account is not working on MSO because when he posts here it shows up at user138194. He's simply confused about the display name (which I can understand, seeing that MSF works completely differently now).

Comment: @user/vgv8 - please see the edit to my answer. meta.stackoverflow.com works differently from meta.serverfault.com. Yes, it's confusing. I completely understand where you're coming from.

Comment: @user, this is normal.  You should got to the following link, and find the button that says "Copy Server Fault Profile to Related Accounts".  This will fix your profile on MSO.  http://serverfault.com/users/47886?tab=accounts#tab-top

Comment: After copying will I be able to edit, comment the closed accounts opened by user138194? Oops, how is it? I opened account first in SO and then copied it to SF

Comment: Yes, you will be able to. All this will do is change cosmetic points of your user account, like your display name. It won't change what is written in your posts, or your access to them.

Comment: Please post your followup question as a **comment** to jinguy's answer, not as an edit to your question.

Comment: @jon, i disagree.  He is adding additional info to the question that will help people answer it in the future.  He should also comment on my answer letting me know his results though.

Comment: @vgv8, looks like you figured it out.  That's good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is normal.  MSO works differently from MSF.  The profiles are not as strongly linked on MSO.

**To fix it:**
You should got to the following link, and find the button that says `"Copy Server Fault Profile to Related Accounts"`. This will fix your profile on MSO.

> https://serverfault.com/users/47886?tab=accounts#tab-top

Comment: You can see formatted version of this comment in revisions in my main question (where it was deleted). Ok, I have restriction of 15 sec. resetting timer. I am trying to add paragraphs one by one

Comment: The "Copy Server Fault Profile to Related Accounts" button is not available (there, in SF), probably because vgv8 is suspended in SF.
Then I am surprised by this advice.

Comment: My account was first created in SO.. Then some my questions were migrated from SO to SF and in SF some questions were migrated to SU. I remember that I already copied profiles but do not remember from where to where.
Cannot I press "Copy Stack Overflow Profile to Related Accounts"?

Comment: My vgv8 account in SO was created 9 months ago, much earlier than in SF

Comment: Does not these questions belong to my main question. I am confused why cannot I add them in OP

Comment: @user, I feel you were right in updating the question the way you did.  You added general information regarding your question.  It was information that would be helpful to anyone reading your question.  After editing your question, you should also leave a comment for me, letting me know what happened when you tried my suggestion.

Comment: @user, what grace means, is go to the following link, and look for the button I mentioned in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/users/200449?tab=accounts#tab-top

Comment: @user, I was not aware that a suspended user could not copy his/her profile to other accounts.

Comment: Thanks, I pressed "Copy Stack Overflow Profile to Related Accounts" (it ws not crystally clear from your comment) and you can see that my post here is now under vgv8. Though, after pressing that button,  "Related Accounts" still showed user138194. An additional refresh (F5) was needed in browser to see vgv8 instead of user138194

Comment: @vgv8, glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 4):

Your account on MSO (meta.stackoverflow.com) is called "user138194". I can see this by viewing your [profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/200449?tab=accounts#tab-top). It shows that SO user vgv8 is linked to MSO account user138194. If you like, you can edit your MSO profile to update your name.

Your account is *not* "blocked from writing" on meta.stackoverflow.com.

Your account *is* suspended on serverfault.com (SF) and meta.serverfault.com (MSF), for reasons discussed in your other posts.

---

Addressing your edits:

The meta for Stackoverflow works differently than the meta for Server Fault.

1. There is no link in the Stackoverflow header for the meta. There is, however, a link in the footer.
2. Your account on meta.stackoverflow.com has its own reputation. Other metas only use your reputation from the main site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the faq, and lurk in the sites for awhile to get a feel for what is acceptable behavior and what is not.

Then you need to wait out your suspension, and try participating again as a *productive* member of the community.

You don't need further explanation.  I have seen your multiple posts here, where the community has tried to explain how the sites work, but you don't appear to be listening.

Comment: General notice: this answer was posted prior to the edits to the question.